# Las imagenes no se muestran al subir aplicación angular al servidor

Tags: angular, imagen, servidor

Estoy subiendo mi aplicación angular a un servidor remoto. La estoy subiendo al directorio /public_html/seacon , por lo tanto ejecuté el comando así: ng build --prod --base-Href=/seacon . el problema es q cuando la subo al servidor las imágenes no se ven. Cuándo inspecciono las imágenes veo que la ruta está asi: ../../assets/images/logo/logo.png  porque así es como la tengo en local. La carpeta assets intente moverla 2 directorios hacia afuera (ya que esta referenciando la imagen asi: ../../ ) pero tampoco las muestra. Que debo hacer para arreglar este problema? Gracias de antemano al que pueda ayudarme, se lo agradecéis mucho.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu `index.html` tiene una etiqueta mas o menos así

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

Eso indica que, todos los assets se cargarán desde la raíz.
Ahora, si tu agregas a tus rutas relativas `../../` esto irá dos niveles antes del root. Hay dos formas, o modificas tus rutas relativas de todas tus imagenes (La mejor práctica) o quitas el `<base>`. Esta última puede tener consecuencias no deseadas.

Comment: Mi index.html actualmente está así:   <base href="/seacon/"> ya que en seacon es donde están los archivos. Si lo cambio a   <base href="/"> la página no carga.